# Прочитать файл в переменную. Как переписать UUID=$(cat machine-id) в bat файл?

Tags: linux, bash, cmd, bat

Функция cat как я понял копирует значение файла /var/lib/dbus/machine-id и заносит в UUID. Как переписать это в bat файл?
Мне необходимо тоже самое выполнить, но только в CMD
(Из .sh в .bat)

```
UUID=$(cat /var/lib/dbus/machine-id)
```

Comment: Используйте *type*.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Is there replacement for cat on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60244/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы эмулировать: [`UUID=$(<machine-id)` из bash](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst#specialities), можно использовать [Set /P в bat-файле для однострочных входных файлов](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html):

```
Set /P UUID=<machine-id.txt
```

Из [ответа @MaxMinecraft101e](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31283158/4279) к вопросу [How to set commands output as a variable in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6359820/4279).